# write function result to a dataobject

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am a little stuck at the moment, I have a function (this works ok) that looks like this.

```
function Addab()
 {
  $a = 1
  $b = 2
  $c = $a+$b;
  return $c;
 }
```

This function is called from an extension of dataobject called Quote the function works as expected and returns the answer in the template as expected.
I would like to also store these results in another dataobject called Archive.
I am just unsure of how to call the function from archive (while matching the quote ID which also needs to be recorded into Archive) and then write it into Archive so it is stored as it is at the time the archive is triggered.

The reason for this is if prices are changed while a quote is current this will change the quote. and i need to keep a record of quotes for later use.

Hope this is enough detail if more is required please ask

any help or ideas would be appereciated thank you

Comment: I think you need to add some more detail to your question. What table would you be entering this result into? Would it be a certain row? What would trigger this? What have you tried so far? A little more detail and we should be able to help you quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to add an archive every time that you run the function addab(), you could just do:

```
function Addab()
 {
  $a = 1
  $b = 2
  $c = $a+$b;
  $archive = Object::create('Archive');
  $archive->c = $c;
  $archive->write();
  return $c;
 }
```

But maybe I am just not understanding your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry the question is still a bit vauge, i was having truble getting it out mostly because i was getting frustrated.I have sice manged to work it out somewhat so i will post an answer soon

Comment: ok i now have it working Rather than creating a new archive everytime the function is called i just needed to get the object to write into. instead of 'code'$archive = Object::create('Archive');'code' i used 'code' $archive = object::get()->filter(array('SomeID' => $this->ID))->first();'code' i will mark this as a right answer because it lead me to the answer. thanks for your help